# Angular: *ngFor trackby Date

Tags: angular, ngfor

my problem is, that I am Iterating over an Array of Dates in an Angular template. The reference of the Dates changes every time, so the view is redrawing what slows down the application. My idea was, to do a "trackby" with Date.getTime() but that doesn't work correctly. The DOM-Elements are recreated yet. That makes the site very slow.

Here's the code example:

```
<div *ngFor ="let month of (months$ | async); trackBy: trackByMonth">
... 
</div>

trackByMonth(index, item) {
    return item.getTime();
}
```

Has anyone an idea how I can avoid the redrawing of the DIV-Elements?

Comment: (months$ | async) means you are getting data from observable mostly http every time right ?

Comment: I get it from a ngrx-store Selector

Comment: in case of trackby ngFor refresh item based on identity, and in you case you are having `getTime()` that might be causing issue , why don tyou just try like this `trackByMonth(index, item) {
    return index;
}` return index rather then time

Comment: @Pranay Rana, yes, I delete my "stupid" comment

Comment: I tried with index but that does not work, too. Also index is not really identifying the object because the months are changing maybe (e.g. starting in may instead of january). If I understand trackby correctly, there have to be returned a unique identifier of the object?

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` with `trackby`, only refresh or add item when item in your array get changed or added or deleted, it doesn based on trackBy function provided as input ,

So if you items keep changing then its not going to help you, so Please check your items not modifying and keep object Identity instead of variable value like time.

to find out more you can make use of developer tool where after each modification in your dom your dom element get highlighted.

Example :

you need to have code as below where items having identifier , to track item and mostly when you add item or modify item then trackby functioon will come in picture and identify each object by its id value

```
 episodes = [
    { title: 'Winter Is Coming', director: 'Tim Van Patten', id: 0 },
    { title: 'The Kingsroad', director: 'Tim Van Patten', id: 1 },
  ];

  *ngFor="let episode of episodes;trackBy: trackById"

    trackById(index: number, episode: any): number {
    return episode.id;
  }
```

Comment: It's actually not possible to keep the object identity. Without trackBy the items are tracked by identity. So i though with trackBy I can change this behaviour, that the items are tracked by another uniquie identifier? In my case the Date...

Comment: @Flash91 - if you that that is going to remain constant then it ok , but if you boject property keep changing then you dom element ger refreshed..check in development tool , to verify that